# How can i reverse the output in my binary adder?

Tags: python, binary

So im trying to create a simple program that will add two binary strings together, im almost done but the output it creates is reversed, how would i implement a way to reverse it in my code? I want to remove the "ob" at the start of the output as well.

```
repeat = True
while repeat==True:

    num1 = input("what number would you like to add ")
    if num1.isdigit():
        a= int(num1)
    elif not num1.isdigit():
        continue
    a = int(num1, 2)

    num2 = input("what number would you like to add to it ")
    if num2.isdigit():
        b= int(num2)
    elif not num2.isdigit():
        continue
    b = int(num2, 2)

    ans = bin(a+b)[2:]
    print("Your addition of numbers, in binary is " + ans)

    choice=input("Would you like to start again, y/n")

    if choice== "y":
        repeat=True
    else:
        print("Its not like i wanted you here or anything baka")
        repeat=False
```

Comment: `if case: ... elif not case: ...` is the same as `if case: ... else: ...` except more computation - use the latter. `isdigit()` also doesn't guarantee `int()` will work! Instead use `try: int(...) except ValueError: ...` to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just reverse the string using:

```
ans = ans[::-1]
```